# How to handle after delete triggers when multiple rows deleted from a table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables, table one *bcdet* having the transaction details and table two *accmast* has the closing balance of all ledger accounts. When I am trying to delete any transaction, the update does not effect.

here is my trigger code.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[tr_ledgerdelete]
on [dbo].[BCDet]
after delete 
as
begin
    declare @dlcode int;
    declare @ddc nvarchar(2);
    declare @dAmt float;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    set @ddc=(select dc from deleted)
    set @damt=(select amt from deleted)
    if (@ddc='C')
    begin
        update accmast set totcr=totcr-@damt where Lcode in (select Lcode from deleted)
        update accmast set clbal=totcr-totdr+opbal where Lcode in (select Lcode from deleted)
    end

    else

    begin
        update accmast set totdr=totdr-@damt where  Lcode in (select Lcode from deleted)
        update accmast set clbal=totcr-totdr+opbal where Lcode in (select Lcode from deleted)
    end

end
```

Comment: `update does not effect` elaborate?

Comment: during update all the clbal field in accmast table update by same amount.@damt and @ddc varible does not changing at all it hold first value from deleted table and based on that value every Clbal field is updated in accmast table.

Answer (score 0):

The inserted and deleted tables can contain multiple rows, so the use of variables is not recommended in triggers.

Also, if Lcode is not unique to the transaction being deleted, using it as the where predicate could allow your update to fire on too many rows.

Without knowing a schema it's difficult to say.  This sample should overcome the first issue.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[tr_ledgerdelete]
on [dbo].[BCDet]
after delete 
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    update t 
    set totcr = t.totcr - d.amt
    from accmast t 
    inner join deleted d on t.lcode = d.lcode
    where d.dc='C'

    update t 
    set totdr = t.totdr - d.amt
    from accmast t
    inner join deleted d on t.lcode = d.lcode
    where d.dc != 'C'

    update t 
    set clbal = t.totcr - t.totdr + t.opbal
    from accmast t
    inner join deleted d on t.lcode = d.lcode

end
```